# TortoiseGit icon overlays showing modified when it isn't

Tags: git, tortoisegit

On one of my repos TortoiseGit shows the red exclamation mark (indicating a modified file), but I have not modified it. Diff'ing the repo shows no changes. It has been like this for a while, during which time I have made commits; after a commit it flicks to a green tick for a second or two, before returning to a red exclamation mark. My two other local repos do not have the same problem. I have read other threads and have tried the following without any luck:

- Refreshing Windows explorer
- Rebooting
- Killing TGitCache.exe in task manager
- Switching 'Unversioned files mark parent folder as modified' on and back off
- Switching the status cache to none and back to default
- Switching OverlaysCaseSensitive to false

Very grateful for any help.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: this is caused by the **core.autocrlf** setting.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have tried switching AutoCrlf to false, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Does Status Cache setting to "Shell" help?

Comment: Setting it to 'Shell extended' seems to have fixed the problem! Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

## Dirty Workaround: Try fiddling with "Status Cache"

*(Answer inspired by comment on original question.)*

You can set several options for the icons here:

```
TortoiseGit | Settings | Icon Overlays | Status Cache
```

And there's a nice and big [list of pros and cons in the TortoisGit docs](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-dia-overlay).

But it was an easy choice for me: There were only two acceptable options for me.

Because I had the same problem and wanted recursive updates. And only the `"Default"` and `"Shell Extended"` options will work recursively. -- And in my case `"Default"` did NOT work. So I just tried the only remaining one: `"Shell Extended"` and that did the trick. (I did not care about any of the disadvantages listed in the docs.)

But that's only a hacky **workaround**. I'm not super happy with it. Since `"Default"` really SHOULD have worked. (And each of the methods has a list of "Disadvantages" in the docs entry.)

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had an empty tracked folder - git doesn't track empty folders. This happened when I moved the contents of the folder. I deleted the empty folder and the overlay changed back to green.